# Why is this definition of the mesaure $\mu$ not properly?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider the measurable space
$$
(\left\{a,b,c\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}},\mathfrak{A}),
$$
where $\mathfrak{A}$ is the product topology on $\left\{a,b,c\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ which is generated by the cylinder sets
$$
[a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_m]_n:=\left\{x\in\left\{a,b,c\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}: \forall 0\leq i\leq m: x_{i+n}=a_i\right\},~~a_i\in\left\{a,b,c\right\}\forall 0\leq i\leq m.
$$

Now, I have a (probably very silly) question. Define a measure $\mu$ on this measurable space, by setting $\mu(\left\{a,b,c\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}})=1$ and 0, else.

Why is $\mu$ not defined properly?

Comment: Choose some measurable B, not empty and not the whole space X, then mu(B)=mu(X\B)=0 but mu(X)=1, which is absurd.

Comment: Any cylinder set  C is measurable, not empty and not the whole space X. Then $C^C$ (complement of $C$) is measurable, too and is not the whole space. Thus $\mu(C^C)=\mu(X\setminus C)=\mu(X)-\mu(C)=0$. But by definition it is $\mu(X)=1$, so that $\mu(C^C)=1$. Right?